# How to prevent a directory from being edited

Tags: linux, directory, xattr

How to prevent a directory (including all of its contents), from being edited?

Using command `chattr`, you can prevent a directory from being deleted:

```
chattr +i folder
```

But, you can edit this directory(`folder`).

So how can i prevent it from being edited (I.e: deleted, writing, creating a file and...) ?

Also, i want to know how to prevent a directory from anything! So no one can delete, edit, or even read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `chattr +i`, you can't edit the directory. You'll find that adding, renaming, and removing files does not work—that's all that is actually in a directory. In order to prevent editing the files, you need to `chattr +i` them, too. (Remember: Unix has hardlinks; a single file can exist in multiple directories.)

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, a read-only bind mount may do what you want. You can make one like this:

```
# mount --bind /source/path /dest/path -o ro
```

Now any access via `/dest/path` will not be able to change the files and directories at all (but access via `/source/path` still can). You can prevent access to the source the normal ways (e.g., have it inside some directory with permissions `go-x` set).

Or maybe what you're doing will work if you just remove write permission, recursively, with a simple `chmod -R o-w the-directory`.

> Also, i want to know how to prevent a directory from anything! So no one can delete, edit, or even read it?

`wipe`, `shred`, or even plain `rm` would be the normal ways. Ok—that's somewhat sarcastic. If you mean no one other than yourself, then `chmod go-rwx the-directory`. If you mean not even root, then the best bet is to put it on some removable media and remove it. If you must keep it online, SELinux can do this—but that adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: And, how can i undo that `mount ...` ?

Comment: @ShayanPeyghambari `umount /dest/path` (just like any other mount).

Comment: I want to design a judge. So a user will send a source file to the server, and server will run it. I want to make the server secure. So i don't want the source file to be able to change some important files/directories. I can't use `mount --bind...`, because in that point, the source file is not able to even print something. (That source file should print the answer.)